# Python SQL Order by a variable

Tags: python, sqlite, variables, sql-order-by

am trying to sort an SQLite query by using a variable but it appears the value of the variable is not being passed and I am confused as to why not.
This is my coding:

```
searchdate="2020-06-01"
sortorder1="Flights.Callsign"

cursor = cur.execute("SELECT  Aircraft.ModeS, Flights.Callsign, Aircraft.Registration, Aircraft.ICAOTypeCode, Flights.FirstAltitude, Flights.LastAltitude,Flights.StartTime FROM Flights left join Aircraft on Flights.AircraftID=Aircraft.AircraftID where StartTime like (? || '%') ORDER BY ? DESC", (searchdate,sortorder1,))
```

the value for the other variable, searchdata is being passed just fine.
Even tried ONLY passing the sortorder1 variable but still not passing the value.

Clearly I am doing something so obviously wrong, that I have overlooked it, but what?

Comment: You can only use placeholders for values, not column names. So you're effectively ordering by a constant string, which is equivalent to no ordering at all. Just include the `sortorder1` value directly into the query string.

Comment: I knew it was something so simple, thank you.  
Thing is I would like to change the sorting order depending on the value of the variable.
Is there a way to do that at all, or do I need to write 4 separate queries with 4 separate sort orders?

Comment: You should be able to do something like `cursor = cur.execute(f"SELECT  Aircraft.ModeS, Flights.Callsign, Aircraft.Registration, Aircraft.ICAOTypeCode, Flights.FirstAltitude, Flights.LastAltitude,Flights.StartTime FROM Flights left join Aircraft on Flights.AircraftID=Aircraft.AircraftID where StartTime like (? || '%') ORDER BY {sortorder1} DESC", (searchdate,))`

Comment: wonderful Nick, thank you ever so much.. and I even understood what you have done, which is even better :)

Comment: no worries - I'm glad it helped.